# Solidjs library rollup configuration: unresolved dependencies

Tags: rollupjs, css-modules, solid-js

I try to build a solidjs npm lib using rollup to provide some components. I intend to build esm and cjs module using the following `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import postcss from "postcss";
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";

export default {
  input: "./src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/index.cjs.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: "dist/index.esm.js",
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  external: [
    "@suid",
    "@suid/icons-material",
    "@suid/material",
    "solid-js",
    "solid-js/web",
  ],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    postcss({
      autoModules: true,
      plugins: [],
      sourceMap: true,
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
    }),
    typescript(),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Unfortunately, i cannot build this. Here's the error message:

```bash
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
~/MonthPicker.module.css (imported by "src/MonthPicker.tsx")
~/DatePicker.module.css (imported by "src/DatePicker.tsx")
@suid/icons-material/ExpandLess (imported by "src/MonthPicker.tsx")
@suid/icons-material/ExpandMore (imported by "src/MonthPicker.tsx")
created dist/index.cjs.js, dist/index.esm.js in 849ms
```

If I understood correctly, `nodeResolve()` is supposed to help here, but i guess i have misconfigured it.

EDITS:

- added postcss as @snnsnn proposed
- removed `babel` from this post (it seems this is a rollup issue)

Comment: Can you share a github repo with basic functionality?

Comment: https://github.com/edelmeier/solid-timeline

Comment: Edited the answer, your app compiles with said changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing postCss plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss

Edit:

1. You are missing some peer dependencies like postcss, @babel/core and I believe that is why you receive "unresolved dependencies" error. I installed them as dev dependencies, but it is better if you add them as `peerDependencies`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@suid/icons-material": "^0.5.1",
    "@suid/material": "^0.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss-modules": "^2.1.1",
    "solid-js": "^1.6.9",
    "suid": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@suid/vite-plugin": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-solid": "^0.9.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.2",
    "rollup": "^3.10.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.34.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "vite": "^4.0.4",
    "vite-plugin-solid": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

2. Used following rollup.config.js:

```js
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss-modules';

export default {
  input: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/index.cjs.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: "dist/index.esm.js",
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  external: [
    "@suid",
    "@suid/icons-material",
    "@suid/material",
    "solid-js",
    "solid-js/web",
  ],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    postcss({
      autoModules: true,
      plugins: [],
      sourceMap: true,
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
    }),
    typescript(),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

3. Used a simple application as `index.tsx`:

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import style from './app.module.css';

export const App = () => {
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Clicking');
  };

  return (
    <div class={style.app}>
      App! <button onClick={handleClick}>Some Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(App, document.body);
```

Your project compiles:

```bash
pnpm run build

> @edelmeier/solid-timeline@0.0.1 build **snipped**/solid-timeline
> rollup -c


./src/index.tsx → dist/index.cjs.js, dist/index.esm.js...
created dist/index.cjs.js, dist/index.esm.js in 1.6s
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @snnsnn. I have added the plugin, but it seems I have also been failing at something different, please see my edits above.

Comment: So, finally I have been able to test this. So, basically what you propose is creating an app rather than a lib and exporting an app rather than an index of components?

Comment: You can export it as lib but the problem is you setup is unnecessarily complicated and using rollup serves no purpose since you have vite. With vite you can remove babel and few other dependencies. Similarly exposing common js module and esm module is unnecessary since the end user can convert into whatever they prefer. Esm is goood enough.

Comment: There's treasure in your last comment. I was going wrong from the get-go. I will modify my setup to follow the `vite` library development guidelines and not care about `cjs`